# In Deep RL methods if we set the Learning rate to 1 then what happens?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

If we set the learning rate to 1 in RL models

1. The updating process will be very slow
2. The agent will always get the low reward
3. The new q-value will always be the same
4. The agent wont’t consider the previous experience in calculating the Q-value for a given state -action pair

Answer (score 0):

Answer: 4,
if the learning rate is 1, the estimate for the Q-value for a given state-action pair would be the straight up newly calculated Q-value and would not consider previous Q-values that had been calculated for the given state-action pair at previous time steps